# jQuery form validation - CSS of error label

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I am using the exact same example used on the jquery website for a simple form validation;
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

There is one thing I don't understand though, the error message in the example is displayed to the right of each input field. I want to display the errors under each input field. How does that work? I tried playing around with the width and padding but no luck so far.

The CSS code I am using is slightly altered, but still very simple;

```
label { width: 10em; float: left; }
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; }
p { clear: both; }
fieldset {position: absolute; left: 450px; width: 400px; } 
em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
```

Here is the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nBv7v/

Comment: Can you please post a jsfiddle or similar so we can see the behavior?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nBv7v/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Quote OP:  "the error message in the example is displayed to the right
>   of each input field. I want to display the errors under each input
>   field. How does that work?"

You can simply change the default element from `label` to `div` by using the [`errorElement` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  Since `div` is "block-level", it will automatically wrap to another line.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div',
        // your other rules and options
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/

You don't even have to mess with the CSS.  But if you need to change anything, target them with `div.error`.

```
div.error {
    /* your rules */
}
```

---

See [the documentation for more Validate plugin options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Answer (score 6):

The `label` element is an [`inline element`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm) and not a `block-level` element. In other words, by default the `label` element will not start a new line.

In order to do that, you can override its default styling like so:

```
label.error {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    ...
}
```

See [**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nBv7v/2/) based on your own.

Comment: @Student No problem. I actually prefer Sparky's solution better, since it employs a documented plugin option instead of messing with the plugin's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `display: block` on `label.error`, this way, it will display in the next line. Now the only thing you have to do is add more padding to `label.error`, or use a table or something to align the error under the text box.

In the jsFiddle you posted, the following modification would put the error message under the text boxes:

```
label.error { display: block; float: none; color: red; padding-left: 11.5em; vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as use this class and this css.

```
.has-error input{
  background: rgba(166, 66, 66, 0.69);
}
```